# Making a simple Javascript version of a gaussian distribution

Tags: javascript, math, gaussian, bell-curve, rune.js

I am trying to draw a series of rectangles (or lines) that follow the height of a gaussian curve. I will need to tweak the distribution manually, because I want to accomplish the very specific curve attached - where it goes up to a spike and back down - [reference image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMng3.png)
Or is there an easier equation to just start small, get large, then small again?

Based on the [gaussian curve function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) I have tried this:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 10;
var x = 20;
var c = 10;

for (var j=0; j< 15; j++){
r.rect(100+j*12, 10, 6, 10*j*((a * Math.E) - (Math.pow(j-b),2))/(Math.pow(c,2)))
.fill(0)
}
```

if the r.rect looks weird, it's from the [rune.js](http://runemadsen.github.io/rune.js/index.html) library.

Comment: Pretty sure your math is wrong. You should only have one subtraction, the horizontal translation. (On my phone but later I can type up your math to show you).

Answer (score 2):

Your math is incorrect. Here is what you wrote in standard mathematical notation:

[image]

I'm not familiar with rune.js, however, here's a simple implementation of a Gaussian curve in pure JS.

```js
const a = 100
const b = 25
const c = 10

const cv = document.getElementById('c')
const ctx = cv.getContext('2d')

for (let j = 0; j < 150; j++) {
    const y = a / (Math.E ** (((j - b) ** 2) / (2 * (c ** 2))))
    ctx.rect(j * 10, cv.height - y, 10, y)
    ctx.stroke()
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" height="200" width="500" />
```